# NetBeans Profiling Menu....missing?

Tags: java, netbeans

I just downloaded & installed NetBeans IDE 6.9 and have been customizing it for the last few hours. I finally just realized that there is supposed to be a **Profile** menu that gives me access to memory profiling features, snapshots, running the GC, viewing HeapWalker, etc.

It's **missing**!

The only thing remotely close to the Profile Menu that I can find is the View >> Toolbars >> Memory Toolbar, which gives me access to forcing the GC and taking snapshots. But I want the whole set of profiling features!

I went into the Help Dialog and according to it, the Profile Menu should be there...but it isn't!

Do I have to activate something in order to get Profile to be a visible menu or am I missing something here?!?

Thanks!

Comment: I have Netbeans 6.9.1 on Windows, it's there. It's either you disabled something while customizing or something really weird is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to `Tools -> Plugins` and search for `Java Profiler` plugin.