# NetBeans profile menu missing

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling, netbeans-8

I'm trying to profile my java project using NetBeans, and I'm looking at http://wiki.netbeans.org/ProfilerFirstSession and https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/getting-started-with-netbeans-profiler-81

However, both links (as well as other websites) assume there is a menu (or button) for profiling, but I see nothing anywhere for profiling other than the button for "profiling the IDE".

It's a vanilla install from Lubuntu.

```
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.1 (Build 20151231-debian-8.1)
Java: 1.8.0_131; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.131-b11
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_131-8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b11
System: Linux version 4.4.0-77-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)
User directory: /home/***/.netbeans/8.1
Cache directory: /home/***/.cache/netbeans/8.1
```

I did see this question: [NetBeans Profiling Menu....missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4874837/netbeans-profiling-menu-missing) but that is several versions old, and apparently, profiling is no longer a plugin but is built in instead. (I could be wrong, but it doesn't show up as a plugin either).

Comment: So, if you click Tools -> Plugins -> Installed, there is no Java Profiler plugin?

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer. I feel kind of stupid for not seeing it before.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, so I'll post it here.
I had to go to the Settings tab in the Plugins window and enable the appropriate Update Center. These were not enabled from a clean install.